Docfx generate PDF
Describe the bug
PDF generate isn't located where I believe it'd be after following the documentation.
I might have misunderstood something, so I hope somebody could help.
To Reproduce
Here's my docfx.json
{
  "metadata": [
    {
      "src": [
        {
          "files": ["**/*.csproj"],
          "exclude": ["**/bin/**", "**/obj/**"],
          "src": "../"
        }
      ],
      "dest": "api"
    }
  ],
  "pdf": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/**.yml"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "api/**",
          "**/bin/**",
          "**/obj/**",
          "_site_pdf/**",
          "**/toc.yml",
          "**/toc.md"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [ "articles/images/**"]
      }
    ],
    "overwrite": "specs/*.md",
    "dest": "_site-pdf"
  },
  "build": {
    "content": [
      {
        "files": [
          "index.md",
          "articles/**/*.md",
          "articles/**/*.yml"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "_site/**",
          "**.*.pdf"
        ]
      },
      {
        "files": [
          "api/**/*.md",
          "api/**/*.yml"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "resource": [
      {
        "files": [
          "articles/images/**"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "output": "_site",
    "template": [
      "default",
      "modern"
    ],
    "globalMetadata": {
      "_appName": "BKS.Gmud",
      "_appTitle": "Gmud",
      "_enableSearch": true,
      "homepage": "index.md",
      "pdf": true,
      "pdfTocPage": true,
      "pdfFileName": "Manual-GMUD.pdf"
    },
    "postProcessors": ["ExtractSearchIndex"]
  }
}

Expected behavior
After running docfx pdf````, I though a folder _site-pdf```` would have been generated.
Screenshots

It was generated under _site/articles/

Context (please complete the following information):

Docfx version: 2.77.0+bd00e2b93951e9e7fa6e5abd990d2cd77d7a83bd

I've tried changing pdf section, globalMetadata but it still generated under _site.
I'd like to have a different place since _site is on .gitignore
